# Can a Judical Misconduct Complaint be read or searched for?

Tags: court, judicial-review, judiciary, misconduct

I have read a news article stating that 15 misconduct complaints were filed against Justice Kavanaugh to the "federal appeals court in Washington, D.C."

I found that searching the "https://www.cadc.uscourts.gov" site yields the transfer papers, but not the complaints themselves (as can be seen in the attached image below).

From the transfer memos, I can see `Judicial Misconduct Complaint` Numbers to be `DC-18-90066` (and few other numbers). How can I read the complaint itself?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[It cannot](http://www.uscourts.gov/judges-judgeships/judicial-conduct-disability/faqs-filing-judicial-conduct-or-disability-complaint#faq-When-will-orders-on-my-complaint-be-published?) until the complaint has been ruled on. [Examples](https://lawprofessors.typepad.com/files/ethics-complaint.pdf) of specific complaints can be [found online](http://www.uscourts.gov/rules-policies/judiciary-policies/ethics-policies/code-conduct-judicial-employees/judicial-conduct-disability-opinions) only if the author(s) publishes them after the Court has ruled on it, or the court issues an order based on the complaint. If you want Orders specific to Judge Kavanaugh, they'll appear either [here](https://www.cadc.uscourts.gov/internet/misconduct.nsf/DocsByRDate?OpenView&count=100&SKey=201810) or [here](https://www.ca10.uscourts.gov/ce/misconduct/opinions).

Comment: So if the person who filed the complaints never publishes them - then the complaint will never be published via the court system?

Comment: If the person who filed doesn't publish them AND the court dismisses the complaint, yes. If the court hears the complaint, the order (which often quotes from the complaint) will be posted.

Comment: I have looked on the last link you provided, and the last ruling from August 2018 was a dismissal. `https://www.ca10.uscourts.gov/sites/default/files/misconduct/10-17-90025.J.pdf`- The Judge in question is not mentioned, nor the name of the complaining person. So how did the news outlet get the count of complaints against Justice Kavanaugh?

Answer (score -1):

> From the transfer memos, I can see Judicial Misconduct Complaint
>   Numbers to be DC-18-90066 (and few other numbers). How can I read the
>   complain itself?

Unfortunately, the entities in charge of disciplining unfit judges are too secretive. If you notice, not even the authorship of grievances is disclosed. This secretiveness facilitates judicial impunity, and it is part of how the corrupt judiciary protects itself from reasonable, justified reproach by civilians.

Reading the complaints you inquire about would be possible only if their authors come forward and publish them. This what I did about the [grievance](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aNwkyCaC4t5VgL5jzYKmzTEop8D8UZBH/view) I filed to denounce Michigan judge/felon Carol Kuhnke. And so did the special prosecutor some months later, apropos of [having busted her](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/2018/04/felon-carol-kuhnke-seeks-reelection-as.html) for illegal possession of narcotics (see [prosecutor's grievance letter](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iytYD9JlvC8lIVLe96ylolUZdvT76wTe/view) and excerpts of the [underlying report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8xAaQygLWnolVEY06LR5d6qE5ZlSThA/view) made by the police).  The impunity to which I refer in the previous paragraph is not hyperbole: On both matters, the Michigan Judicial Tenure Commission declined to proceed against the felon.

Comment: Whoever voted down, would you please substantiate your reason for doing so? Or is it that you are very close to the judiciary and therefore dislike candor?

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds as if you are setting a self-experience theory, rather than a systematic answer. The question in place is where can a complaint be found. Not if the system is corrupt.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I have to say that I am generally uncomfortable with your habit of tying your answers to cases in which you were personally involved, and your general assertions of widespread corruption in the legal system.  It gives the impression that your answer is intended more to publicize your own views than to actually address the question, and I think it detracts from the otherwise useful information that you obviously have.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for both your favorable and unfavorable remarks. I certainly address the questions... it is not just a coincidence when OPs accept and/or show gratitude for many of my answers as applicable to their inquiries. As for my criticism, people need to be aware of the judicial corruption that undeniably exists. The lack of awareness thereof has been making much easier for the crooked members of the judiciary to do as they please instead of doing their job: To follow the law. A judge has much more power (and uses it) to crush a person's life than legislators or even presidents do.

Comment: @IñakiViggers While I agree that judicial corruption should be exposed, I don't think this is the place for it. Law.SE is for providing answers to people's legal questions, not for publicizing your views.

Comment: @osdavison Stackexchange is clear that answers which are primarily opinion-based are discouraged. But that does not mean that any and all views premised on experience or verifiable sources are prohibited. People need to be mindful that what statutes & legal precedents say is often very different from how judges operate. Otherwise, by silence we are condemning unsuspecting victims/litigants to a rude awakening in court.